# Expected value of ceiling of a random variable

Tags: expectation

I have a continuous non-negative random variable $X \ge 0$ defined by a black-box cumulative distribution function $F(x) = \Pr [ X \le x ]$. In other words, I have an algorithm to calculate $F(x)$ for a particular value of $x$ but no closed formula.

I am interested in the expected value of a ceiling of $X$. In other words, define another random variable
$$
Y = \lceil X \rceil = k, \text{ if $k-1 < X \le k$}.
$$

Is there a way to calculate $\mathbb E[Y]$?

I thought of the following. We can find a distribution of $Y$:
$$
\Pr [Y = k] = \Pr[k-1 < X \le k] = F(k) - F(k-1)
$$
and then by definition:
$$
\mathbb E[Y] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \left(F(k) - F(k-1)\right)
$$

Can this formula can be somehow further transformed to something that is easier to calculate than just, say, calculate the sum of the first $100$ terms?

P.S. $\mathbb E[Y]$ has obvious bounds $\mathbb [X] < \mathbb [Y] < \mathbb[X]+1$ but it is rather loose.

Comment: depending on the accuracy needed, you could get an approximation for $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ by generating random variables with your known distribution.

Comment: If you don't have further information you cannot do better as applying the formula of $\mathbb{E}Y$. For start with the distribution of $Y$. Then you have $F(k)$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. And $F$ can be any increasing, leftcontinuous function on the the intervals $[k,k+1)$, $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ ("blackbox").